# How to send more than 200 contacts to server in android?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, android-contacts

I am getting contacts from my android device using cursor.Successfully gets all the contacts.If cursor count below 200 it successfully saves the server otherwise it crashes.

i am preparing the json array of all the contacts and send to the server but more than 200 contacts i am dividing the contacts and send to server but it does not accept it returns 400 error code.below is my log cat.(i am sending 100 contacts to server at a time)

```
05-12 18:35:11.170: I/Timeline(18091): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@15a30238 time:1943759
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091): org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head><title>Apache of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at com.example.gettingcontacts.MainActivity$DoBack_process.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:194)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at com.example.gettingcontacts.MainActivity$DoBack_process.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
05-12 18:35:15.370: W/System.err(18091):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Thanks in advance.

**below is my sample code**

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("Server URL");
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("user-agent", "Yoda");
            try {

                myjson = new JSONObject();

                myjson.put("userID", 15);

                myjson.put("contacts", finalJarray);


                //Log.e("json request is","request is "+myjson.toString());

                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(myjson.toString());

                entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json; charset=utf-8"));

                request.setEntity(entity);

                // Send request to WCF service
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

                int resCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                //InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                //tempresult = convertStreamToString(instream);
                //instream.close();
                resultcontact = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                //Log.e("resultent value is ", "result value " + result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        try {
        jobj= new JSONObject(resultcontact);(this line i am getting the error)
        String message=jobj.getString("message");
        }
         catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("login activity","...do back catch block....");
        e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

05-12 20:35:13.416: D/MainActivity(10734): My string to send - Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu) - Error report

## HTTP Status 400 -

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Maybe your JSON is not well formated because of this `Value Apache of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`, I recommend you this JSON validator: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: We can't understand the problem without code.

Comment: @Tofasio Thanks for reply,my json is good why because below 200 contacts it successfully saves the server does not throw any exception.

Comment: @hegazy give me your mail id i am sending sample to your mail

Comment: @Ashok Don't use `AsyncTasck` for long operation :)

Comment: Please, post it here so that anyone having the solution can answer and to document the question in case anyone face the same problem later.

Comment: @Abdellah then how to call services?

Comment: @Abdellah i am trying runnable it throws the android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Hi I updated my code please check it.

Comment: Add Log.d(TAG, String.format("My string to send - %s",  resultcontact)); after you getting that value. And show this value to us.

Comment: I am edited,i have 230 contacts in my devise first 100 contacts are saved successfully but second 100 contacts shows the above exception

Comment: @Ashok I think that question was answered. You have error in your server side code. Create new question with code from server side.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending HTML instead of JSON. Check out your exception text:

```
JSONException: Value <html><head><title>Apache of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

**upd:**
mr. @ci_ - is absolutely right and probably real reason is in a server side. For some reason (probably) it can't handle JSON with 200+ contacts. But as well OP doesn't provide any information (code for instance), I don't think that it possible to answer something clear here.

Comment: You may have been a bit fast here. Granted, there isn't a lot of detail in the question, but I believe the error you see is from trying to parse an error page returned from the server as JSON. While this clearly won't work, I think the actual question was, why does the server return an error (400)? (This of course can't be answered from the detail in the question).

Comment: yes but below 200 contacts it correctly sends the JSON above 200 contacts i am having the issue,it does not create the json object.